# Particle Collision with Static System

Tags: simulations, particle-physics, optimization

I have a system of particles with equal distance with each other and another at random positions which is moving with time. What I want to know is :

1. The method by which I can reduce the number of particles from the first system, as I know the maximum motion of any particle is X (**Meaning: Maximum displacement from starting to end of simulation is X)**.
2. How to efficiently calculate the collision between them, I have heard about quadtree and octree but (as per I understood till now) they are for collision of particle from each other. In my problem,second system of particles doesn't collide with each other.

Note: Sorry, if it is a very basic question, I am (very) new to this field.

**Update:**

[image]

### **The combined System**

[image]

### **Movable parts (Same color means same radius and mass)**

[image]

### **Unmovable Grid (Colors means nothing and yes, it's a cube of spheres)**